# When I open my index.php page, it opens showing the bottom

Tags: php, html

When I open my index.php page, it opens showing the bottom, I want it to open normally, at the top. How can I do that?

Comment: please add some more details or create a fiddle to help you more.

Comment: Will share my link, please open it from a cell phone and you will see that it shows the bottom of the web page instead of the top. http://withoutlyrics.com/

Comment: can't get your point. can you add a screen shot

Comment: if by *"opens showing the bottom"* you mean that when the page loads it's scrolled down to the bottom of the page then note that i'm not getting that when i load your url in Chrome 53.0.2785.116 on Windows 7

Comment: Yes!, that is what I meant.

Comment: When I open the page using my laptot , google chrome browser it opens normally. But when I open the page from my ANDROID cell phone, the page shows the bottom.

Comment: @Allan that ^ would be useful information to add to your question. generally it should be opening your website at the top of the page unless you use an anchor link so something in your code is probably doing this. you'll need to post that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `autofocus="on"` from your form input fields, the first thing I notice when the page loads is the input has cursor focus, and since it's below the fold the browser is scrolling downwards.

Answer (score -7):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how does a button that creates an javascript alert saying *"Hello World!"* even remotely answers the question. if i am totally missing the point then it's a good time to learn to stop posting only code blocks and actually explain them